# pdfcluster density estimation - predicting on a new data point

Tags: r, predict, kernel-density

I have a very large data frame (500K rows, 50 columns), for which I want to calculate the density estimate.

Since pdfCluster cannot handle this kind of dimensions, I was wondering if there is a way to calculate the density based on a sample of, say, 10K points and predict on the other 490K.

However the result of pdfCluster just gives the point estimate at the 10K points, and I can't find an underlying function/object from which to extrapolate on the new points.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You question is not clear - how do you want to perform pdf (row or column wise)? why not to use `density`?

Comment: for each row, I would like to get the multivariate density estimation. But since this is computationally expensive for all the rows, I would like to do it for a sample of the rows and predict on the rest

Comment: The function density seems to calcualte for each column independently from the others - I need the multivariate density